# I am getting this weird ERROR while executing my code it was working normally 3 days ago

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32, win32com, mapi

```
 from win32com.client import Dispatch
 outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
 root_folder = outlook.Folders.Item(1)
```

**AttributeError: module 'win32com.gen_py.00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x9x6' has no
attribute 'CLSIDToPackageMap'**

Hi everyone,
I am receiving this error while connecting Python to outlook, It was working normally 3 days ago, but suddenly it returns this error, I don t know why, do you have any idea please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending emails from outlook with Python not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58267574/sending-emails-from-outlook-with-python-not-working)

Comment: Maybe this might help you [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58267574/sending-emails-from-outlook-with-python-not-working)

Comment: No it doesn t  :( I tried it

Comment: What property or method exactly gives the error? Where do you run the code? Is it a web server or service?

Comment: I am using anaconda Navigator (anaconda 3) Jupyter Notebook. The problem is that the code was working perfectly... but then nothing works anymore and it returns this error. The ERROR is related to the second line when I wanted to connect to the outlook :( I really need help everything is blocked now :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution to this error, you just need to clear and keep the folder **C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py** empty and then you try this code:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
outlook=win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
my_folder = outlook.Folders.Item(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's basically the answer, but the test script will never work, since you import "Dispatch" not "win32com.client.dynamic", which is what you use in the call. Just eliminate the parent classes and call "Dispatch" directly, e.g., outlook=Dispatch("Outlook... (blah blah blah)